# replace space with -, but not when - is already there

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

i am trying to get product names out of my database and rewrite them, the names look like this:

```
Romper bedrukt met tekst - Lime maat 68
```

This is my rewrite:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $testlink['name']);
$string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
```

When the name is:

```
Romper bedrukt met tekst - Lime maat 68
```

it needs to do this:

```
Romper-bedrukt-met-tekst-Lime-maat-68
```

But it does this:

```
Romper-bedrukt-met-tekst--Lime-maat-68
```

You can see the double --, because, in the first preg-replace, i remove all strange characters except numbers and letters, but when a name already contains a -, there will be 2 spaces. My second replace fills them with two --.

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something as simple as this:

```
$string = 'Romper bedrukt met tekst - Lime maat 68';
$slug = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $string));
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Note that `\W` will not a match an underscore character, either. If you want it to be replaced too, then make the character class more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing your first replace replace " - " and any iterations of it (such as " -" "- " and "-") with space.

Answer (score 0):

For those specific cases:

```
$string = str_replace(array(' -','- ',' '), '-', $testlink['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("--", "-", $string);
```

Or merge all spaces into one:

```
$string = preg_replace( "/\s+/", " ", $string );
```

This second method will cover most or "strange" texts.

EDIT: 
And shorter way. Two steps: remove strange characters and replace one-or-more-spaces into "-":

```
$string = preg_replace( "/\s+/", "-", $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
$string = 'Romper bedrukt met tekst - Lime maat 68';
$string = preg_replace("/[ -]+/", "-", $string);
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Romper-bedrukt-met-tekst-Lime-maat-68
```